# SQL Server table - Update Order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with fields: `id, city, country`. I imported this table from Excel file, everything is imported successfully, but `id` field is not ordered by number. The tool I use imported the rows in some random number.

What kind of Update command I should use from SQL Server Management Studio Express to re-order my ids?

Comment: In any relational database, you don't "reorder" your ID's - you only ever get any order if you specifically use `SELECT (columns) FROM dbo.YourTable ORDER BY ID` in your queries - that's the only way to "order" anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a primary key and a clustered index on your table? If not, `id` is a good candidate for a primary key and when you create that the primary key it will be the clustered index.

Assuming this is your table

```
create table CityCountry(id int, city varchar(10), country varchar(10))
```

And you add data like this.

```
insert into CityCountry values (2, '2', '')
insert into CityCountry values (1, '1', '')
insert into CityCountry values (4, '4', '')
insert into CityCountry values (3, '3', '')
```

The output of `select * from CityCountry` will be

```
id          city       country
----------- ---------- ----------
2           2          
1           1          
4           4          
3           3
```

A column that is primary key can not accept null values so first you have to do

```
alter table CityCountry alter column id int not null
```

Then you can add the primary key

```
alter table CityCountry add primary key (id)
```

When you do `select * from CityCountry` now you get

```
id          city       country
----------- ---------- ----------
1           1          
2           2          
3           3          
4           4
```

Comment: I have my purpose, i know why i want this order, so any advices why do you want this, there's no much sense are not useful for me at the moment.

My table don't have a relation with another table, so no cascading will happen. There're no null values in my id column.

My ids are custom ordered 87, 3, 15, 123, 56, 4 - so, i don't want to rename or re-counter them, i don't want the records to be in the order they are now. I want to be in order they were before import (ordered by id). So, the answers of Jose Rui Santos, Mikael Eriksson are not solution in my case.

Comment: @user569008, it would be really helpful if you could add some sample data to your question, both before and after the update. What I suggested and what Jose Rui Santos suggested will give you different results. If you do what I say the rows will be reordered. The solution from Jose changes the id for the rows. I do not understand how there can be a third way of doing this.

Comment: The query of Thomas, i'm not sure i understand what exactly it does. When I try to use Thomas's query it says "Invalid column name 'NewId'."

Comment: Example: My records at the moment: record 1: id: 34, country: germany, city: berlin; record2: id: 2, country: usa, city: new york; record3: id: 325, country: england, city: london. Let's say i have 10 000 records. I want my records to be physically re-ordered by id (not renamed or not only using select). When I open the table i want to see them ordered by id.

Comment: I totally agree with what Mikael Eriksson said. If you want the rows ordered by id, then just add a PK and clustered index as demonstrated by Mikael's solution. If you want to reorder and rename ids, just use mine. Did you try them at least? I also don't see a third way of doing this.

Comment: I'm really sorry guys. Mikael Eriksson's is the correct solution. I'm not so good in SQL and i try it wrong, so i thought it was wrong. But i try it again and it solved my problem. Thanks for all your support :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the order by part of the select statement to order them.

Comment: I know about Select and Order By commands. I don't want to select, i want to update, make an action. Is it possible to tell me if such command exists?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want all the ids to have consecutive numbers 1,2,3,4...

Image your table contents is:

```
select *
  from yourTable

id          city       country
----------- ---------- ----------
1           Madrid     Spain
3           Lisbon     Portugal
7           Moscow     Russia
10          Brasilia   Brazil

(4 row(s) affected)
```

To reorder the ids, just run this:

```
declare @counter int = 0

update yourTable
   set @counter = id = @counter + 1

(4 row(s) affected)
```

You can now check, that indeed all the ids are reordered:

```
select *
  from yourTable

id          city       country
----------- ---------- ----------
1           Madrid     Spain
2           Lisbon     Portugal
3           Moscow     Russia
4           Brasilia   Brazil

(4 row(s) affected)
```

However, you need to be careful with this. If some table has a Foreign key to this `id` column, then you need first to disable that FK, update this table, update the values in other tables that have FK's pointing to yourTable finally enable again the FKs

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you may have some misconceptions about the purpose of the Id column. The Id column is probably a surrogate key; i.e. an arbitrary value that is unique and non-null that is never shown to the user. Thus, it should not be implied to have any inherit meaning or sequence. In fact, you should always have another column or columns that are marked as being unique to represent a "business key" or a set of values that are unique to the user. In your case, `city, country` should probably be unique (although you will likely need to add province or state as it is common to have the same city exist in the same country multiple times.)

Now, that said, it is possible to re-sequence your Ids if the following are true:

1. The Id column is not an identity column. Since this was from an import, I'm going to guess this is true.
2. There does not exist a relationship to the table where Cascade Update is not enabled.
3. You are using SQL Express 2005 or later:

```
Update MyTable
Set Id = T2.NewId
From    (
        Select Id
            , Row_Number() Over ( Order By Id ) As NewId
        From MyTable
        ) As T1
    Join MyTable As T2
        On T2.Id = T1.Id
```